# Change text of a <label> element with php code ( wordpress )

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress website and i ran into a problem with translation. I installed a plugin for product measurement calculator and i translated parts of it using Loco translate plugin. But some parts of that plugin ( some elements and strings ) won't translate ( see picture under )

[image: plugin part that wont translate]

Under this text is a html that shows how this element looks like! I would like to change this "Length (cm)" located in `<label>` element to "Visina zida" and I don't know how to do it. I tried using `str_replace()` function but I most likely didn't target that element well since I'm not that good with PHP.

Can some one please help me make a php code for functions.php that can change this text? Thanks!

```
<tr class="price-table-row length-input">

<td>
<label for="length_needed">Length (cm)</label>
</td>

<td style="text-align:right;"><span class="dashicons dashicons-editor-help wc-measurement-price-calculator-input-help tip"></span>
<input type="text" name="length_needed" id="length_needed" class="amount_needed" data-unit="cm" data-common-unit="m" autocomplete="off">
</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: _I most likely didn't target that element well_ So how DID you target it?

Comment: _"Can some one please help me make a php code for functions.php that can change this text?"_ - you'd basically have to "catch" all of the created output at the very end (WP does not really have a default mechanism for that, but if you do a bit of research, you should find some "late" hooks that could be suitable for the purpose), and then either search&replace in there, or use a DOM parser ... But it would really make more sense to ask the plugin author, to please make those texts translatable as well.